# mocha chai passes the test even if result is not as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js, chai

I use mocha, chai, express to test REST API response
the response status is 201 and I expect to fail the test

```js
it('janus post', () => {
  request('https://***')
    .post('/***')
    .attach('file', 'T:/***/Test1.docx')
    .end(function(err, res) {
      if (err) throw err;
      expect(res.status).to.be.equal(200)
      console.log(res.body);           
  });
});
```

the test is passing and the result is:

```bash
     First test

        ✔ janus post


      1 passing (399ms)

    C:\projects\testacademyapi\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:950
        throw err;
        ^
    AssertionError: expected 201 to equal 200
        at Test.<anonymous> (C:\projects\apitests\tests\webApi.spec.js:28:38)
        at Test.assert (C:\projects\apitests\node_modules\supertest\lib\test.js:172:8)
        at localAssert (C:\projects\apitests\node_modules\supertest\lib\test.js:120:14)
        at C:\projects\apitests\node_modules\supertest\lib\test.js:125:7
        at Request.callback (C:\projects\apitests\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\index.js:857:12)
        at C:\projects\apitests\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\index.js:1070:18
        at IncomingMessage.<anonymous>    (C:\projects\apitests\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\parsers\json.js:21:7)
        at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:526:35)
        at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
      showDiff: true,
      actual: 201,
      expected: 200,
      operator: 'strictEqual'
    }
```

I expect fail of the test.

Comment: That network request is async, the test function you're passing into `it(...)` isn't, so that's probably not going to do what you want. You probably want to use `(done) => { ... }` and then call `done()` when your _actual_ test finishes running, inside that `.end` handler.

Comment: You may want to include the post request code in your question above.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand
could you give a code example?

Answer (score 0):

I modified code, added done()
and it works now.

Now the code looks like:

```
it('janus post', (done) => {
  request('https://***')
    .post('/***')
    .attach('file', 'T:/***/Test1.docx')
    .end(function(err, res) {
      if (err) throw err;
      expect(res.status).to.be.equal(200)
      done();
      console.log(res.body);           
  });
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).